# Howto Base64 decode (library) in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, base64

There are lots of Base64 libraries for Java SE but I can't seem to find one for J2ME.

Does any one have a algorithm or library in their coding toolkit?

I receive following from a REST webservice (cut for clearity) :

```
[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,1,64,0,0,0,46]
```

How do I decode the string above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](http://vc.thauvin.net/cvs/BlueMonger/src/com/bluemonger/j2me/Base64.java?revision=1.1.1.1&content-type=text/plain&view=co) code.
Confirm it once.

Comment: Thank you much, Jigar Joshi.
I've successfully decoded my string value with this code in J2ME!
Umid.

Comment: @JigarJoshi help me with this. Link you provideed above goes to profile of Erik C. Thauvin. I didnt find any code there.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Please help me in this. I haven't find any code in above link. I need it badly. I was waorking on since last week and no update in this till now.