# Parse String respresentation of byte array in JavaME

Tags: blackberry, java-me, base64

I sending a byte array over a REST service. It is being received as String. Here is an extract of it. with start and end tags.

`[0,0,0,0,32,122,26,65,0,0,0,0,96,123,26,65,0,0,0,0,192,123,20,65,0,0,0,0,0,125,20,65,71,73,70,56,57,97,244,1,244,1,247,0,0,51,85,51,51,85,102,51,85,153,51,85,204,51,85,255,51,128,0,51,128,51,51,128,102,51,128,153,51,128,204,51,128,255,51,170,0,51,170,51,51,170,102,51,170,153,51,170,204,51,170,255,51,213,0,51,213,51,51,213,102,51,213,153,51,213,204,51,213,255,51,255,0,51,255,51,51,255,102,51,255,153,51,255,204,51]`

Now before anyone suggests sending it as a base64 encoded String, that would require Blackberry to actually have a working Base64 decoder. But alas, it fails for files over 64k and Ive tried alsorts.

Anyway this is what ive tried:

```
        str = str.replace('[', ' ');
        str = str.replace(']', ' ');
        String[] tokens = split(str,",");
        byte[] decoded = new byte[tokens.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {           
            decoded[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);             
        }
```

But it fails. Where split is like the JAVA implementation [found here.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/String-Manipulation-split-replace-replaceAll/ta-p/620038)

Logically it should work? but its not. This is for **JavaME / Blackberry**. No Java Answers please (unless they work on javaME).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems one minor and one that is a pain.
Minor:whitespaces (as mentioned by Nikita)
Major:casting to bytes ... since java only has unsigned byte, 128 and higher will become negative numbers when casting from int to byte.

```
    str = str.replace('[',' ');
    str = str.replace(']', ' ');
    String[] tokens = split(str,",");//String[] tokens = str.split(",");
    byte[] decoded = new byte[tokens.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        decoded[i] = (byte) (Integer.parseInt(tokens[i].trim()) & 0xFF);
    }
    for(byte b:decoded) {
        int tmp = ((int)b) & 0xff;
        System.out.print("byte:"+tmp);
    }
```

(btw:implementing base64 encoder/decoder isn't especially hard - might be "overkill" for your project though)

Comment: Its not overkill when Im transfering images over the web constantly. Ive tried many different implentations of base64 decoder and it doesnt always work. Throwing decode error. the static method cant parse over 64k, and the read methods randomly fail for something that should be decodeable (Works with static method if less than 64k). Thanks for the unsigned byte observation though!

Comment: Works great. Thanks. And for explaining what you did (in terms of the unsigned byte). I might try and embed it into the split code. No point going through the array twice ;).

Comment: Look at the base64 implementations you've tried to use, rewrite them so that they instead of saving the result into a local buffer (max 64k on your device would be my guess) use streams, one stream with the input and another for the output - maybe the output can go to a file or something? You probably need to handle padding at each 4-byte block and not at the beginning which most implementations does. The code in the link in the link in Rafael's answer looks like a good base.

Comment: Ive tried code that follows the logic of your suggestion. But it randomly fails, obtained from blackberry forums, but it randomly fails.

Answer (score 1):

Replace brackets with empty strings, not with spaces:

```
str = str.replace('[', '');
str = str.replace(']', '');
```

In your case you have following array:

```
[" 0", "0", "0", ..., "204", "51 "]
```

First element `" 0"` cannot be parsed to Integer.

Comment: Its a bit strange why " 0" cannot be parsed to an integer? the Reason I used a space is because `''` is invalid character constant. And I assumed it would parse the space. Using `''` in javaME atleast, is not possible. I can however call .trim() before parsing which sorts the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use Base64 encoded string to send byte array.

There's [a post with link to Base64 library for J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657047/howto-base64-decode-library-in-j2me).

This way allows you convert byte array to a string and later you can convert this string to byte array.

Comment: Yep, in my question I do point out ive tried this already. The link you supplied is only usable for a `base64String` representation of a `string` rather than a `byte[]`